# IOS iphone 4s not repainting dynamic images that are initially outside the viewport

Tags: ios, safari, background-image, viewport, repaint

I have been suffering from a bug for sometime:

I am doing something like the following:

```
$container.on('touchmove', function(){
   $container.trigger( 'lazyload.appear');
});

$img.one( 'lazyload.appear', function(){
   var that= this;
   var $self= $(that);
   $self.css('background-image', "url('real.path.to.img')" );
 });
```

However, on IOS there seems to be a problem with repainting the background-images, when they are initially outside the viewport.  When I drag my finger, until the image is in the viewport, the images aren't painted onto the screen unless i release my finger.  I'm trying to aim for real-time, so I would like the image to be revealed as soon as I do a touchmove, but its being revealed at touchend when its initially outside the viewport.  However, the console.log outputs that the background-image has changed before releasing my finger.  When the image is inside the viewport, the repainting is fine, it repaints instantly as I drag my finger.

This seems to be a bug, or am I missing something?  Thank you for your help!

Comment: also i have tried to force repainting by using: $img.css('display', none') $img.css('display','block') before and after the background image being set

Comment: ive also tried $ele.addClass('repaint').removeClass('repaint') and with vanilla js using selector.style.display="none"; selector.offsetHeight; selector.display="block"; neither seems to work.

Comment: any solutions? we're seeing the same problem. the only known fix is changing device orientation, but this needs to be done by the user.